# Rails collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

Manager `:has_many` `:interns`, `:through => :assigns`
Intern `:has_many` `:managers`, `:through => :assigns`

I am trying to create a new assign record. This is the assigns/new view where a given authenticated **intern** is creating a new association with a **manager**:

```
# assigns/new.html.erb
<% form_for @assign, :url => {:action => "create"} do |p| %>
  <%= p.label "Select Manager", nil, :class => "label" %>
  <%= collection_select :assign, :manager_id, @managers, :id, :manager_name, options ={:prompt => "Select a manager"}, html_options ={:class =>"listBox", :style => "width:25em;"} %>
  <%= p.hidden_field :intern_id %>
<% end %>

# assigns controller
def new
  @intern = Intern.find(params[:id])
  @assign = Assign.new(:intern_id => @intern.id)
  render :layout => 'centered'
end

def create
  @assign = Assign.new(params[:assign])
  @assign.manager_id = params[:manager_id]
  if @assign.save
    redirect_to :controller => "interns", :action => "home"
  else
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

The problem is: `manager_id` = `nil`. Why? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out following or

```
@assign.manager_id = params[:manager_id]
```

OR replace with

```
@assign.manager_id = params[:assign][:manager_id]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this line

```
@assign.manager_id = params[:manager_id]
```

You're already assigning the `manager_id` in the line before

```
@assign = Assign.new(params[:assign])
```